# Checking if list elements are in string index list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, which ones I want to compare their elements:

A remote list called `groups`

```
groups = [
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'digital-academy'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'amazon'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'plaza'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'staging'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'almere-busbaan'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'eneco-zoc'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'healthcare'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'test'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'parametric-lab'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'femtest'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'bridge'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'geluidsschermen' },
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'speckle-staging'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'bern'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'maritime-research'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'aviation'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'mijnbouwstraat'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'evoluon'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'treehouse'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'training'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'monarch'},
{'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'ferdi'}
```

]

And a local list called `local_groups`

```
local_groups = ['speckle-staging', 'eneco-zoc', 'parametric-lab', 'digital-academy',
            'amazon', 'almere-busbaan', 'healthcare', 'femtest', 'maritime-research',
            'mijnbouwstraat', 'evoluon', 'treehouse', 'training', 'ferdi',
            'bern', 'bridge', 'plaza', 'monarch', 'staging', 'aviation',
            'geluidsschermen', 'test']
```

`groups` and `local_groups` lists contain the same amount (and same names) of groups in their `name` attribute. I want to check if `groups` elements are present in `local_groups`, that is not a problem at all.
But when I check if `local_groups`elements are in `groups`, I got the following behavior:

```
local_str_groups = " ".join(str(x) for x in local_groups)
print("String of local groups \n", local_str_groups)
for group in groups:
    if group['name'] not in local_groups:
        print(group['name'], "aad group, is not present in local_users file")
    elif local_str_groups not in group['name']:
       print("group doesn’t exist on remote list, please create it")
    else:
        print("AAD groups and local groups are synchronized")
```

I got `group doesn’t exist on remote list, please create it`, so looks like `local_str_groups not in group['name']` condition is getting true despite the amount and content of items are the same in both list ...

How can I make it distinct when the `local_list` elements are different to `groups` list elements?

Comment: By `local_str_groups not in group['name']`, you are checking if the string `local_str_groups` is NOT contained within the string `group['name']`, but the `local_str_groups` has **BIGGER** length than `group['name']`. Of course it is always going to evaluate to `True`. I do not really  to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Countour-Integral I got it. `local_str_groups` is a large string with spaces ... of course. 
I am trying to check if the elements on `local_groups` are in `groups`. The thing was that I had to convert `local_groups` to string first to make it works with `in`  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use set() in order to find difference between the groups

```
local_groups = ['speckle-staging', 'eneco-zoc', 'parametric-lab', 'digital-academy',
                'amazon', 'almere-busbaan', 'healthcare', 'femtest', 'maritime-research',
                'mijnbouwstraat', 'evoluon', 'treehouse', 'training', 'ferdi',
                'bern', 'bridge', 'plaza', 'monarch', 'staging', 'aviation',
                'geluidsschermen', 'test']
local_groups_set = set(local_groups)

groups = [
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'digital-academy'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'amazon'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'plaza'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'staging'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'almere-busbaan'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'eneco-zoc'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'healthcare'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'test'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'parametric-lab'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'femtest'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'bridge'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'geluidsschermen'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'speckle-staging'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'bern'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'maritime-research'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'aviation'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'mijnbouwstraat'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'evoluon'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'treehouse'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'training'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'monarch'},
    {'id': 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx', 'name': 'ferdi12'}
]

groups_set = set(x['name'] for x in groups)
print(local_groups_set - groups_set)
print(groups_set- local_groups_set)
```

output

```
{'ferdi'}
{'ferdi12'}
```

Comment: @bgarcial if the difference is empty  you can consider it as `False`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to find group names that exist in one list but not two lists.

So here is my solution:

```python
group_names = [f['name'] for f in groups] #only names
for i in group_names:
    if i not in local_groups:print(f"remote group #{group_names.index(i)} not in local_groupes.")
for i in local_groups:
    if i not in group_names:print(f"local group #{local_groups.index(i)} not in remote groupes.")
```

Comment: A simpler (and possibly more efficient) solution would be to convert both to sets, then use set difference iff the sets are not identical.